# Ignoring non-serializable objects in XamlWriter.Save

Tags: xaml, save, xaml-serialization

I have a bunch of WPF controls that needs to be dumped to xaml. Some controls contain non-serializable objects stored in their's Tag property. I need to ignore them during saving Xaml, since I need layout itself, but XamlWriter.Save generates an error that states that they are not serializable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore a property add

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Check out this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/16/xamlwriter.aspx